# Convert object datatype to Integer

Tags: python

```
import numpy as np 
import pandas as pd
data=pd.read_csv(r"C:\Users\Enosh\Downloads\1606807231386.csv")
```

I have a column named winner and it contains object data type and i want to use count function for particular value `data.count("csk")`

Im getting this error:

```
No axis named csk for object type DataFrame
```

Comment: You probably meant something like `len(data.loc[data['winner'] == 'csk'])` or `data['winner'].value_counts()['csk']`.  Check out the docs for [`Dataframe.count`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.count.html) to see why your first attempt was wrong.

Comment: `data.winner.value_counts()`  

I would suggest starting by a structured tutorial before posting this kind of questions.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```py
frequency = data['winner'].value_counts()
```

for more info go to [pandas documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.value_counts.html).